# Grouping By and Referencing Shifted Values

Tags: python, pandas, methods, cumulative-sum

I am trying to track inventory levels of individual items over time
comparing projected outbound and availability. There are times in
which the projected outbound exceed the availability and when that
occurs I want the `Post Available` to be 0. I am trying to create the
`Pre Available` and `Post Available` columns below:

```
 Item  Week  Inbound  Outbound  Pre Available  Post Available 
 A        1      500       200            500             300 
 A        2        0       400            300               0 
 A        3      100         0            100             100 
 B        1       50        50             50               0 
 B        2        0        80              0               0 
 B        3        0        20              0               0 
 B        4       20        20             20               0
```

I have tried the below code:

```
def custsum(x):

      total = 0
      for i, v in x.iterrows():
         total += df['Inbound'] - df['Outbound']
         x.loc[i, 'Post Available'] = total
         if total < 0:
            total = 0
      return x

df.groupby('Item').apply(custsum)
```

But I receive the below error message:

```
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

I am a relative novice to Python so any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Please copy and paste the Data Set Mockup *as text* to make it easy for us to reproduce your DataFrame.

Comment: How do I add as a text? The info seems to look weird when I attempt to do so

Comment: tem Week Inbound Outbound Pre Available Post Available
A 1 500 200 500 300
A 2 0 400 300 0
A 3 100 0 100 0
B 1 50 50 50 0
B 2 0 80 0 0
B 3 0 20 0 0
B 4 20 20 20 0

Comment: @Charles adding into your question type edit

Comment: How is `Pre Available` supposed to be calculated?

Comment: Pre Available is supposed to be previous week Post Available + Inbound for that current row. I also want to make sure that the min value for Post Available is never below 0. Thank you!

Comment: Should `Post Available` be 100 on the third row since `total` on the previous row is reset to 0 and the `Inbound - Outbound` equals 100?

Comment: My mistake! Yes it should indeed. I'll edit that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Inbound': [500, 0, 100, 50, 0, 0, 20],
                   'Item': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Outbound': [200, 400, 0, 50, 80, 20, 20],
                   'Week': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
df = df[['Item', 'Week', 'Inbound', 'Outbound']]


def custsum(x):
    total = 0
    for i, v in x.iterrows():
        total += x.loc[i, 'Inbound'] - x.loc[i, 'Outbound']
        if total < 0:
            total = 0
        x.loc[i, 'Post Available'] = total
    x['Pre Available'] = x['Post Available'].shift(1).fillna(0) + x['Inbound']
    return x

result = df.groupby('Item').apply(custsum)
result = result[['Item', 'Week', 'Inbound', 'Outbound', 'Pre Available', 'Post Available']]
print(result)
```

which yields

```
  Item  Week  Inbound  Outbound  Pre Available  Post Available
0    A     1      500       200          500.0           300.0
1    A     2        0       400          300.0             0.0
2    A     3      100         0          100.0           100.0
3    B     1       50        50           50.0             0.0
4    B     2        0        80            0.0             0.0
5    B     3        0        20            0.0             0.0
6    B     4       20        20           20.0             0.0
```

---

The main difference between this code and the code you posted is:

```
total += x.loc[i, 'Inbound'] - x.loc[i, 'Outbound']
```

`x.loc` is used to select the *numeric* value in the row indexed by `i` and in
the `Inbound` or `Outbound` column. So the difference is numeric and `total`
remains numeric. In contrast,

```
total += df['Inbound'] - df['Outbound']
```

adds an entire Series to `total`. That leads to the `ValueError` later. (See below for more on why that occurs).

---

The conditional

```
if total < 0:
    total = 0
```

was moved above `x.loc[i, 'Post Available'] = total` to ensure that `Post
Available` is always non-negative.

If you didn't need this conditional, then the entire `for-loop` could be replaced by

```
x['Post Available'] = (df['Inbound'] - df.loc['Outbound']).cumsum()
```

And since column-wise arithmetic and `cumsum` are vectorized operations, the calculation could be performed much quicker.
Unfortunately, the conditional prevents us from eliminating the `for-loop` and vectorizing the calculation.

---

In your original code, the error

```
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

occurs on this line

```
x.loc[i, 'Post Available'] = total
```

because `total` is (sometimes) a Series not a simple numeric value.  Pandas is
attempting to align the Series on the right-hand side with the indexer, `(i, 'Post Available')`, on the left-hand side. The indexer `(i, 'Post Available')` gets
converted to a tuple like `(0, 4)`, since `Post Available` is the column at
index 4. But `(0, 4)` is not an appropriate index for the 1-dimensional Series
on the right-hand side.

You can confirm `total` is Series by putting `print(total)` inside your `for-loop`, 
or by noting that the right-hand side of

```
total += df['Inbound'] - df['Outbound']
```

is a Series.

Answer (score 2):

There is not need a self-define function , you can using `groupby` + `shift` for create PreAvailable and using `clip`(setting the lower boundary as 0 ) for `PostAvailable`

```
df['PostAvailable']=(df.Inbound-df.Outbound).clip(lower=0)
df['PreAvailable']=df.groupby('item').apply(lambda x  : x['Inbound'].add(x['PostAvailable'].shift(),fill_value=0)).values
df
Out[213]: 
  item  Week  Inbound  Outbound  PreAvailable  PostAvailable
0    A     1      500       200         500.0            300
1    A     2        0       400         300.0              0
2    A     3      100         0         100.0            100
3    B     1       50        50          50.0              0
4    B     2        0        80           0.0              0
5    B     3        0        20           0.0              0
6    B     4       20        20          20.0              0
```